# Convert Python to C#

Tags: c#, python, .net

Hi I'm trying to convert som Python code to C# I'm struck understanding this line of code

```
n = int(e[2:10], 16)
```

`e` is a string looking like this:

```
0100000180a6fa85de8dd3381cc277b046d7e3856307519d03da4e3ff5dca52de833c56951ab3e539a161df98454be311fd242407b25bf7b8e84c322f06f913d712393922bd1477d2cf3a9d2ba14bb00f8b2d7a203376afed0e1782e49ea55d43cee8e3bb8331f3f8aa81955bae8fcd118f640b4cd49d787bd8a12d57f424b371d07f08de67ab8f40bf5894288920adfe9480cfbec7deef073c3f137d71dff9d4ab967d9178648961cd2def00d376cf01dca6a4c6428243cef23eeab9791f5cd7d66f5293879b7ed83abf600f78426491c57c8a61e
```

Comment: Looks like its converting a hexadecimal to int.

Comment: Yes 16 is the base ... but what about e[2:10] is that for position 2 and then 10 chars? OR it is from pos 2 to 10?

Comment: maybe [this](https://github.com/uxmal/pytocs) will help you

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: Why won't you just run the code? It seems to return a slice from the 3rd to the 10th element inclusive for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n = int(e[2:10], 16)` takes characters 2..10 from `e` and interprets them as hexadecimal characters to interpret as an integer.

That is, for your input,

```py
>>> e = '0100000180a6fa85de8dd3...'
>>> f = e[2:10]
>>> f
'00000180'
>>> int(f, 16)
384
```

so you should be able to do the same with something like `Convert.ToInt32(e.Substring(2, 8), 16)` in C#.

Answer (score 2):

At first, you're using string slicing (from 2nd to 9th character) using [2:10]. Then you're converting them to (decimal) `int` from `hexadecimal`. 
Which will result `n = 384`.